# How are Error Correcetion Levels Encrypted in QR Code?

Tags: encryption, qr-code, error-correction

I'm trying to create my own QR Code Generator library and algorithms.
I made a little research about the steps of creating a QR Code, but got stuck with this ambiguous point.

Error Correction Level are listed as following:

- Level L (Low)     7% of data bytes can be restored.
- Level M (Medium)  15% of data bytes can be restored.
- Level Q (Quartile)    25% of data bytes can be restored.
- Level H (High)        30% of data bytes can be restored.

> In QR Codes **Black = 1** & **White = 0**

According to **Wikipedia** this how levels are coded

- **L** : **3 (11 binary)** -> (2 Black squares)
- **M** : **2 (10 binary)** -> (1 Black & 1 White)
- **Q** : **1 (01 binary)** -> (1 White & 1 Black)
- **H** : **0 (00 binary)** -> (2 White squares)

According to **lots of other Websites & Tutorials** this how levels are coded

- **L** : **1 (01 binary)** -> (1 White & 1 Black)
- **M** : **0 (00 binary)** -> (2 White squares)
- **Q** : **3 (11 binary)** -> (2 Black squares)
- **H** : **2 (10 binary)** -> (1 Black & 1 White)

Which one do I trust or I have missed a critical step or something to identify that

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is **BOTH**, yes both are correct but are a *different phases*:

- The one in **Wikipedia** show how the Error Correction Level is displayed on a **READY QR CODE** *(final preview)*
- The others show how the Error Correction Level should look like **Before MASK**

> In QR Codes not only Data and error correction are masked, also format strings (15 bits) are masked too but with a particular mask:

> **The 15 bits format string are XOR-ed with the following 15 bits 101010000010010**

> So as Error Correction Level is always represented in the first 2 bits it will always be masked (XOR-ed) with these 2 bits **10**

So the final result would look like the following:

- **L : 1 (01 binary)** -> 01^10 = 11 -> **Becomes 3 (11 binary)**
- **M : 0 (00 binary)** -> 00^10 = 10 -> **Becomes 2 (10 binary)**
- **Q : 3 (11 binary)** -> 11^10 = 01 -> **Becomes 1 (01 binary)**
- **H : 2 (10 binary)** -> 10^10 = 00 -> **Becomes 0 (00 binary)**